Pydantic model not recognizing multipart POST request in FastAPI
I'm trying to send a POST request a FastAPI endpoint. This request includes both json data and a file.
results = requests.post(
            f"http://toing_url:{_e('TOING_PORT')}/toing",
            json={
                "m_type": self.m_type,
                "models_list": self.model_names,
                **self.payload_inputs
            },
            files={
                'arr': compressed_arr_file
            }
        )

The FastAPI endpoint thazt accepts this request is as follows.
@APP.post("/toing")
async def invocations(
    request: Request,
    m_request_body: MRequestBody,
    image_arr: UploadFile
):

    image_arr_decoded = await image_arr.read()
    ...

from pydantic import BaseModel

class MRequestBody(BaseModel):
    m_type: str
    models_list: list
    ...

Python's requests sets the request content type as multipart/form-data. This gives me a 422 error. However when I remove the files part form the request and from the endpoint, the request is accepted by FastAPI. I noticed that when I remove the files param, the request is sent as application/json.
Is there anyway I can send the file and the json in the same request and get my FastAPI's pydantic model to accept the json data?
